# Android ImageView cycle colors

Tags: android, animation, transparency, imageview, alpha

I would like to quickly cycle the tint of an image that I have loaded within an imageview. This is what I currently have. I am also using a transparent background color for `myimage`. This does not work though.

```
    AlphaAnimation transparency = new AlphaAnimation(1, 9);
    transparency.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    transparency.start();

    ImageView myimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimageid);
    myimage.setBackgroundColor(0x66F00000);
    myimage.startAnimation(transparency);
```

What will make this work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the reference:

> Parameters
>
> fromAlpha     Starting alpha value for the animation, **where 1.0 means fully opaque and 0.0 means fully transparent**.

Assuming you want to animate from 10% to 90%, you need to set the parameters as `new AlphaAnimation(0.1f, 0.9f);`

Comment: I changed that but my image is not cycling at all. Just a static image. How do I make it start, and how do I set how fast it cycles

Comment: Did you add a duration to it?

Comment: I don't know about that function, so no. Can you elaborate on what will make this work properly? I want it to run until stopped, run forever

Comment: Check this blog post: http://ttlnews.blogspot.com/2010/08/endless-flashing-textview-animation-in.html

Comment: Thanks Duration was it! I was looking for "duration" instead of "setDuration"